# Input redirection for script in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I was wondering if it was possible to provide values for variables in an SQL script that accepts user input. This is a small part of a larger assignment (one question involves writing a script which has to invoke another script, which in turn requires user input). I cannot alter the script that requires user input.

For simplicity's sake, assume I have the following in `foo.sql`:

```
ACCEPT TABLENAME CHAR PROMPT 'Enter Table: '
SELECT * FROM &TABLENAME;
```

Once I am already logged into SQL*Plus, is there a way for me to execute `foo.sql` and redirect input in a way similar to Bash? In an ideal world, I would be able to do this as follows:

```
@foo < "SOMETABLE"
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can redirect input from a file to the `sqlplus` command itself, before you login:

```
> sqlplus user/pwd@db @foo < input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think that may be the only way, I didn't have any luck finding a similar mechanism within `sqlplus` itself. I'm fine with this method myself, but the assignment spec doesn't specify how the markers will enter the data. Usually it's automated, but they may do it manually (or redirect into `sqlplus` itself as you have).

I'll leave the question open for another day or so, just in case somebody has a way to redirect within sqlplus itself, but I'll accept your answer if that doesn't happen. I'll email my lecture in the meantime and get some clarification.